# Override CloudBees' lift version

Tags: lift, cloudbees

Currently CloudBees' default Lift version is 2.4, and this is what you get when using the Lift ClickStart.  What's the best way to use Lift 2.5-M1 instead?  Create a ClickStart and override the default version, or some other way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clickstarts are designed to be "forkable" and updatable - if you want to use a newer lift version - take a look at:

https://github.com/CloudBees-community/lift_template

Fork it, change the pom.xml (as it currently uses the maven build type) ** - to use the appropriate version, and push your changes.

You can then rerun the clickstart via pasting a URL like the following into your browser

https://grandcentral.cloudbees.com/#CB_clickstart=https://raw.github.com/YOUR_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/lift_template/master/clickstart.json

and it will use the newer version. Submit a pull request if you like - so it is up to date for future.

If you have an existing app you created - you can just clone the git repo, update the pom.xml and push it - it will then update your app for you.

Here is a guide on making your own ClickStart: http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/How+to+make+your+own+Clickstart

Comment: Thanks!  Btw, you guys have done some really excellent work with Cloudbees in the past few months, either/both in terms of your offerings and communicating them all via your website.  Bravo.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments - that means a lot.

Comment: Gladly, I feel like I've just rediscovered Cloudbees for the first time after initially evaluating it a few months ago.  Jumped to #1 choice for all my JVM projects (all Lift right now) - only PaaS with literally *all* my boxes checked.  Looks like a great team behind it, will look forward to seeing what else you guys roll out.